# Does --i and i-- behave the same way as ++i and i++?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, stack

I recently looked up what is the difference between ++i and i++ and found that apparently it doesn't matter in for loops but it does in this case:

```
int i = 3;
int a = i++; // a = 3, i = 4
int b = ++a; // b = 4, a = 4
```

Does it work the same for --i and i--? I am wondering because I have come across the following exercise:

```
// pops the first non-null element in a stack
public E popFirstNonNull() throws EmptyStackException {

while ( (top >= 0) && ( S[top] == null ) ) {
    top--;
}
if ( top >= 0 ) {
    E topNonNull = S[top];
    S[top--] = null; //for garbage collection
    return topNonNull;
}
else {
    throw new EmptyStackException();
}
```

}

If `++i / i++` and `--i / i--` behave the same shouldn't this line: `S[top--]=null;`  be changed to: `S[--top]=null`

Comment: Think about entering that branch with `top == 0` and what your proposed change does.

Comment: The previous line is `E topNonNull = S[top];` so the value you want to `null` is `S[top] = null; top--;`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks, that is what I thought! But I am assuming that S[top--] would also work in that case because it would still make the old value (which is top) null, is that correct?

Comment: @user3281466 yes.  and this is why you want to decrement only after you have used the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

What the code does is

- remember the top element in `topNonNull`
- null out the top element and then
- decrease the top-"pointer" in the `S[top--]=null` line
- return `topNonNull`

If you change this to `S[--top]=null` then you will null out a different element, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

++i / i++ and --i / i-- behave the same way. You are right impact of both (top-- and --top)are different in your case

```
 S[top--] = null; //null will be assigned to current index() and than it will decrease top.
```

and

```
S[--top] = null; // it will decrease top and null will be assigned to decreased top.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they behave the same.

Regarding the example: no, it should not be changed.
The meaning of

```
S[top--] = null
```

is to replace the value that was just read with null.
So:

```
E topNonNull = S[top];
S[top--] = null; //for garbage collection
```

first reads s[top] and assigns it to topNonNull, then replace the value just read with null, so top must stay the same and THEN it can be decreased to point at the next non-null value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, --i means i = i - 1 BEFORE the compute and i-- AFTER the compute. So it is analog to ++i and i++.

Comment: Thanks. Then according to the exercise writing S[top] is the same as writing S[top--] right?

Comment: S[top] and S[top--] will return the same things, yes. But I don't say it's the same, as top is decreased. That's what you're searching for if I'm right.